unable to run this query in mysql?
Select 
  book_id,
  log, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY log DESC) as ra 
from admin_comments_tbl;

receive a error:

0  8   11:12:48    Select book_id,log,
rank() over(PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY log DESC) as rank from admin_comments_tbl    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY log DESC) as rank from admin_comments_tbl' at line 2    0.046 sec`


RANK is a reserved word even if you lower case it.. change the alias rank to something that's not a reserved word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

The query in the errormessage is different from the query in the code snipped (as ra vs as rank). Please don't edit away the error in your questions after a comment showed them up.

Never post anything without describing what you are trying to achieve and what the desired result is. You won't be likely to get any answers if you do. Tip: use chatGTP to translate if you don't speak English (well), it has a far bigger chance to give a coherent translation, Google Translate won't cut it.

OVER is not a function. The space between OVER and opening parenthesis char should not be skipped.

I suspect you are on a mysql version < 8.0 https://dbfiddle.uk/Vswj3Tak where window functions are not available. Publish the result of select version();

Are you using the obsolete MySQL 5.7? Run select version();.
